# Grunt plugin to create SVG files sprite and also auto update the CSS files with new path

Tags: javascript, svg, gruntjs, sprite, grunt-svgstore

Something like grunt-sprite-generator for images, i need a plugin for svg files.
I tried using **grunt-svg-sprite** grunt plugin, but it only creates sprite and does not modifies the css directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it before but [grunt-spritesmith](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-spritesmith) looks promising.

Comment: This plugin does not update the css paths automatically.

Comment: i'm not sure what you are asking for? why do you want to update the css paths?